# Is there a way to publish the log of the failed section of a build to GitHub checks?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Working on porting a Jenkins plugin to Azure Dev Ops Pipelines plugin (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devopsv ) and I've seen in the docs info about how the logging commands can be used to add annotations to the GitHub checks on the PR that's being build. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands) 
This is great since I don't have to call GitHub APIs myself and create new GitHub App.

But in my tests it doesn't look like Azure Dev Ops Pipelines post the build log on the PR Check. Only annotations are posted. Can we also post the full log of a section that failed on GitHub PR?

If not as plan B, can we get the output of the failed build somehow so that I can manually use GItHub APIs and post it?

Comment: Do you mean that push the logs which displayed in Azure pipeline console to PR checks console in Github? If so, then it sounds like a Github extension such as  [Azure-pipelines](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines). Theoretically, we can call both Azure DevOps and Github APIs to do that, but no experience on that.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Azure-pipleines GitHub extension. Looks like it's posting just the annotations on the PR Checks tab. Not the full log (I only care about the section that failed - but full log is also fine).

Comment: Recommend that you could navigate to the Azure-pipleines extension [Q&A page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.services-github&ssr=false#qna) to ask for the question and submit the feature request. It’s difficult to develop by yourself.